# Comparison between E(X) and E(L(X)) where X is exponential random variable.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$. I want to know how big $E[L(X)]$ where $L(X)=\frac{X-1}{ln(X)}$ is. Essentially I want to compare $E(X)$ with $E[L(X)]$ with respect to $\lambda$.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

Of course we take $L(1) = 1$.  For an upper bound: it looks to me like $L(x)$ is concave, so $E[L(X)] \le L(E[X]) = L(\lambda)$.

Comment: I suspect you intended $L(\frac1\lambda)$ at the end if the parameter is a rate

Comment: The bound looks as if it is within 9% of the true value and often much closer.

Comment: "Parameter" for an exponential distribution is ambiguous: some use a rate parameter, others use a scale parameter.